# Small question about limit at $+\infty$ to $-\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

please the definiton of $\displaystyle\lim_{u\rightarrow+\infty}G(t,u)=-\infty$
is:

$\forall M>0 ,\exists R>0 $ such that $|u|\geq R \Rightarrow G(t,u)\leq M$
or $G(t,u)\leq -M$ ?

please

Thank you

Comment: You could either say $G(t,u) \leq -M$, or first define $\forall M < 0$ and then use $G(t,u) \leq M$.

Comment: so it is : $\forall M>0$.....$G(t,u)\leq -M$ or $\forall M<0$...$G(t,u)\leq M$

Comment: That's what I would say, yes.

Comment: Are you are asking this for $u\in\mathbb R$ or $u\in\mathbb C$? My question arises because you write $|u|$ in the statement. If adapted (e.g. by writing $\forall M$ instead of $\forall M>0$) then it is a definition of $\lim_{\left|u\right|\rightarrow+\infty}G\left(t,u\right)=-\infty$

Answer (score 1):

Since the limit is $-\infty$, then $G(t,u)$ has to tend to be less than negative numbers. Since $M$ is defined as positive, we must have the latter case $G(t,u) \leq -M$.

(An equivalent way would be to change the first part to $\forall M < 0$, in which case $G(t,u) \leq M$ works)